# Call html dataset within a plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<button class="draw-sector-button" data-sector_no="0">Draw first</button>
<section id="section-0"></section>
<button class="draw-sector-button" data-sector_no="1">Draw second</button>
<section id="section-1"></section>
```

An HTML page, has multiple sections, and buttons each.

Clicking a button triggers plugin, then it fills related **section** tag. Problem is, getting tag dataset inside the plugin callback, but *"this"* indicator doesn't work:

```
$('.draw-sector-button').myDrawPlugin({ // my data table generator
    param1 : 'foo',
    param2 : 'bar',
    onComplete : function(result) {
        var i = $(this).data('sector_no'); // (i : undefined)
        $('#section-'+i).html(result.data_table);
    }
});
```

They say the opposite:
"you have access to the actual image node through the this keyword within the callback."
in a [JQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/) page. So I'm confused. Anyone can offer a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please share the **myDrawPlugin** definition to understand how the click event is bound and handled?

Anyway,  **this** inside **onComplete** callback will refer to the object(param) passed to plugin function, hence if you want the button element data to be accessed then you need tp pass the corresponding element reference to  **onComplete** callback when you're invoking it on button click.

See if this way of handling works for you,

```
$.fn.myDrawPlugin = function(opts) {
    // Button click handling
    $(this).on("click", function(){
       opts.onComplete(this, {data_table: "<div>Hello World!</div>"});
    });
};

$('.draw-sector-button').myDrawPlugin({ // my data table generator
  param1 : 'foo',
  param2 : 'bar',
  onComplete : function(element, result) {
    var i = $(element).data('sector_no'); 
    $('#section-'+i).html(result.data_table);
  }
});
```

working snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/d7g8kb1j/1/

Comment: Good idea: returning element reference from plugin. Thank you, it works.
I forgot to place the plugin code, but you guessed the structure well.
$(element).data('sector_no') gets correct value, like stated in html attribute.
Also element.data('sector_no') works well, in this scenario.